# PyQt inside Scene 3D of Blender

Tags: pyqt, blender

I import the PyQt5 library under blender and I created a command interface.
 My problem is that I found myself with two windows (one of blender of course and one of PyQt)
 Is there any way to automatically embed (in the script) the PyQt window inside the Blender 3D scene?
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you will get that to work unless you alter blender's source code and build your own version of blender. While you have access to using a range of widgets that blender uses for it's UI, there aren't any ways to incorporate other GUI toolkits into blender's UI.

Blender uses [python](https://www.python.org/) to define it's user interface and provide access to it's internal data. You can [define your own panels](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Panel.html), which are collapsible groups of UI widgets, that will be incorporated into blender's UI with the existing panels. You can [define operators](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html) to perform custom actions, which are then attached to buttons displayed in your custom panels. You can also [create addons](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html) so that your additions can be enabled every time blender is run.

To get more control over customising the UI appearance you could use the [bgl module](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bgl.html), I'm not certain if this can be used outside of a 3DView but you could turn a 3DView into your custom drawing area.

Comment: thank you for your reply. my goal is to show juste scene 3D and an interface of command automatically when i run a file.blend.

Comment: Have a look at the [sensei format](https://blendersensei.com/new-sensei-format-installer-and-auto-updater/) addon for an example of an addon that changes the UI to the way the developer wants. Using python you can change the window layout to your needs. [Fluid designer](https://www.microvellum.com/solutions/fluid-designer/) is an example that has altered the default UI scripts and I'm fairly sure they also made C/C++ code changes as well.

Comment: thank you, i already create buttons in UI of Blender and it's easy. but when i saw the example of sensei it's complicated. Now i look for a script that delete the tools interfaces of the interface of blender. i want to keep just Scene 3D and my UI interface but i don't know how can i do that